# AdMob ads not shown in my app

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to include AdMob ads in my app but for some reason they are not appearing. When I run the ads with set up id from the guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/eclipse#give_your_app_an_ad_unit_id)

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

I see the test ads but I soon as I change the id to the newly created AdMob ad id I see nothing appearing. Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you are testing it on debug version? Try your ad id and release the app and use the apk.

Generally admob won't show real ad on debug version of the app. If you see test ad than you are absolutely fine with implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try that. :)

Comment: How long ago did you create your ad unit? It can take a few hours sometimes for them to spin up and be accessible.

Comment: @RedBrogdon That was the case actually :D I did create it and I was expecting to work right away! :D Now works fine! Thanks guys! :)